Deserializing Java String into a Java Class using Lift JSON in Scala 3
I'm trying to implement "generic" deserialization in JSON for simple Scala3 types (e.g. case classes) - I need to pass in the serialized JSON and the name (string) of the target class and to receive an instance of the target class (which I treat as a java.lang.Object afterwards).
I chose to use the Lift framework's JSON library. Due to Lift being Scala2 only, I'm using it through the CrossVersion.for3Use2_13 compatibility layer (this is from my build.sbt):
libraryDependencies += ("net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.5.0").cross(CrossVersion.for3Use2_13),
I chose Lift's JSON library due to the availability of explicitly passing the target class for deserialization (see Extraction Lift docs):
def extract(json: JValue, target: TypeInfo)(implicit formats: Formats): Any
To make use of that, I'm first "dereferencing" the class name to a java.lang.Class instance in Java:
String targetClassName = (inp.entrypointClass == null ? "Main" : inp.entrypointClass);
String mainClassName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + targetClassName;
Class targetClass;
try {
  targetClass = Class.forName(mainClassName);
} catch(ClassNotFoundException err1) {
  throw new InvalidEntrypointClassError(err1);
}

This part seems to run correctly (evidenced by the fact that I'm not getting InvalidEntrypointClassErrors in my debugging attempts).
Then I try to deserialize the string into a Class as follows:
import net.liftweb.json._
import net.liftweb.json.Extraction._
import net.liftweb.json.Serialization._
import reflect._

val formats = net.liftweb.json.DefaultFormats

object ScalaWrapper {
    def deserialize(jsonData: java.lang.String, clazz: java.lang.Class[?]): java.lang.Object = {
        val typeInfo = TypeInfo(clazz, None)
        val data = parse(jsonData)
        val res: Any = extract(data, typeInfo)(formats)
        res.asInstanceOf[java.lang.Object]
    }
}

This fails when I try it with simple examples, such as trying to deserialize into the Input case class defined here:
case class Node(name: String, left: Option[Int], right: Option[Int])
case class Walk(nodes: List[Node])
case class Input(nodes: List[Node])

Note that it is important for me to have "simple" case class definitions, that is passing the complexity of the deserialization problem unto the case classes IS NOT a solution due to other requirements
with the following JSON input:
{
        "nodes": [
            {
                "name": "A",
                "left": 1,
                "right": 2
            },
            {
                "name": "B"
            },
            {
                "name": "C",
                "left": 4,
                "right": 3
            },
            {
                "name": "D"
            },
            {
                "name": "E"
            }
        ]
    }

The error is rather deep inside Lift JSON:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ByteCode$.forClass(ClassFileParser.scala:24)
        at scala.tools.scalap.scalax.rules.scalasig.ScalaSigParser$.parse(ScalaSig.scala:68)
        at net.liftweb.json.ScalaSigReader$.findScalaSig(ScalaSig.scala:126)
        at net.liftweb.json.ScalaSigReader$.$anonfun$findScalaSig$1(ScalaSig.scala:126)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:477)
        at net.liftweb.json.ScalaSigReader$.findScalaSig(ScalaSig.scala:126)
        at net.liftweb.json.ScalaSigReader$.findClass(ScalaSig.scala:60)
        at net.liftweb.json.ScalaSigReader$.readConstructor(ScalaSig.scala:44)
        ... <SKIPPED ABOUT 20 OTHER STACK FRAMES>
        at net.liftweb.json.Meta$.mappingOf(Meta.scala:195)
        at net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:210)
        at binary_tree_dfs.ScalaWrapper$.deserialize(ScalaWrapper.scala:13)
        at binary_tree_dfs.ScalaWrapper.deserialize(ScalaWrapper.scala)

I've failed at debugging this and I don't know Scala under the hood to really understand what's going on, but my guess is I'm paying the price for trying to use Scala2 generics features in a Scala3 project. Is that correct? Can this code be fixed without a major refactor?
Since I don't know what's going on here, I've thought about several other approaches:

Tried to get implicit TypeTag or Manifest (I can post non-working snippets). They need to be explicitly passed from the Java side and I don't find any documentation on how to produce those from just a class name. Is that possible?
I'm guessing there's a way to convert izumi-reflect's TypeTags into Scala2 Manifest-compatible objects, but I don't know how to do it and I'm afraid this is hacky and unreliable. Is this approach possible and does it make more sense?
Alternatively, I'm guessing that I can use another Scala3 JSON library that can deserialize into a TypeTag that is provided as (implicit?) argument. Is there a Scala3 library that would allow me to do this without modifying the case classes definitions?
Maybe I can obtain a Scala3 Manifest in another way that I don't understand? Scala3 documentation on Mirror seems scarce. Can I construct a Scala3 method that receives a class name and returns a tuple of both java.lang.Class and Manifest? Does that even make sense if Manifest doesn't have a generic argument?
AFAIU, Scala3 macros are the intended replacement of Scala2's Reflection. Can/should this be done using Scala3 macros?

I know this question is a lot to take in, so thanks for making it this far :)
I've tried hard to provide as much possible info without overcomplicating, but I'd gladly share more context - such as a not-working example that I'm sweating over
Just to summarize the problem:
I'm trying to deserialize a JSON string into a Scala3 class I know only by name.
I expect this class to be a case class. I'm currently trying and failing to use Scala2's Lift JSON library.
I want the case classes that the JSON will be deserialized into to have simple definitions, so I don't want serialize/deserialize methods or similar approaches.
How do I achieve this in Scala 3?

"I chose Lift's JSON library due to the availability of explicitly passing the target class for deserialization" - this makes things easy to mess up. Runtime reflection on JVM works after type erasure, so information about what's inside generics (e.g. Option[Int] vs Option[String]) is gone. From what I see Manifest is used for recovering these pieces of information - but manifests are gone on Scala 3 and they were generated by the compiler.I wouldn't dare to generate them from Java's side by hand. I also would not use Lift for a new projects.

If you want to use Scala 3, I would forget about any JSON library that is not based on some cross-compiled (or Scala 3 only) library - these things depend on code generated by the compiler (usually interfaces, known as type classes, have their implementation provided by some library code based on the type, this process is known as derivation) - since most of these depends on macros at some point (Scala 3's Mirrors are an exception) they are tightly coupled to specific Scala version. for3use2_13 won't let you call Scala 2 macros - either there is no macros or they were already expanded.

I believe Jackson (Scala module) supports Scala 3 for quite some time already.

@MateuszKubuszok Thanks for the comment! Does that mean that my chosen approach of trying to use Lift JSON is dead on arrival? If so, what alternative would you recommend?

@GaëlJ Can you show a snippet in Scala 3 with Jackson that can deserialize case classes such as the ones above, while also receiving the class name as a String argument?
If so, please write an answer and I'll gladly accept it

I saw some tickets on Lift's GH page, where I saw that some modules are yet to be translated to 2.13 (not JSONs though), but there is no ETA on Scala 3 - until they port their macros to Scala 3, yes, using Lift's JSON libraries on Scala 3 is DOA. There is plenty of alternatives: Jackson (if you are not into type classes, but Jackson use runtime reflection, so type erasure is a thing again and it might be an issue?), Circe (if you're into Cats), Jsoniter Scala (ATM codec generation requires manual call to JsonCodecMaker.make but this is the fasted thing on JVM AFAIK), there's PlayJSON as well

@K.Steff there's nothing very special to do. Check out the documentation: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-scala.

@GaëlJ Maybe I'm not seeing it, but when I look at the jackson-scala documentation I don't see how I can convert a java.lang.Class value to a generic JavaTypeable[T] second argument to readValue. If I'm missing something, please share

The link you pointed at is to get "rich" conversion features. Plain old Jackson should be enough for you readValue(... src, Class<T> valueType). On a Mapper instance.

@GaëlJ How could plain old Jackson deal with Option[Int]? It is my understanding that I need the Scala library, otherwise the problem with type erasure reappears. Is there something I'm missing?

@MateuszKubuszok Can you point to an example for one of the libraries you mention that can deserialize case classes such as the ones above, while also receiving the class name as a String argument? In particular, Option[Int], which AFAIU won't work with a simple Java library used from Scala

Jackson (with the Scala module) is able to do what you want (i.e. parsing to a class known at runtime).
package com.myapp

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.{ClassTagExtensions, DefaultScalaModule}

case class Node(name: String, left: Option[Int], right: Option[Int])
case class Walk(nodes: List[Node])
case class Input(nodes: List[Node])


val objectMapper = JsonMapper.builder().addModule(DefaultScalaModule).build() :: ClassTagExtensions

val input: String = ???

val parsedInput = objectMapper.readValue(input, Class.forName("com.myapp.Input"))

println(parsedInput)
// Input(List(Node(A,Some(1),Some(2)), Node(B,None,None), Node(C,Some(4),Some(3)), Node(D,None,None), Node(E,None,None)))

